# It's problem with handling with sass in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, scss-mixins

This failed to compile:

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 8:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (8:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| 
> @import "functions";
| @import "variables";
| @import "mixins";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use next scss plugin

Follow this link to [next-sass](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass)

There you can see a full breakdown of how to handle sass in next.

You need to add a config file like this

### next.config.js

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass({})
```

Then restart your dev process. Sass should work and be transpiled now.

Comment: this answer is not working for me i style getting same error